# Realm.io - How to optimize findAll query?

Tags: android, realm

I have this table:

```
public class Meaning extends RealmObject {

    @Index
    private String key;
    private String value;
    private byte[] entries;

    //getters & setters
}
```

It contains more than 400K objects.
I am taking list of meaning like this:

```
RealmQuery<Meaning> query = realm.where(Meaning.class);
query.beginsWith("key", word);
RealmResults<Meaning> meaningList = query.findAll();
meaningList.sort("key", true);
return meaningList;
```

Result looks like this:

```
r:6593ms
re:3459ms
rea:3416ms
real:3137ms
realm:3237ms
real:3298ms
rea:3084ms
re:712ms
r:289ms
:6539ms
```

For incremental search, this result is not good. So my question is how to optimize findAll query?

Answer (score 0):

When I created objects, I thought, by putting @Index on **key** makes this column indexed. At least, it is strange it does not sort objects automatically. Maybe I do not understand Realm deeply. After hours of try-error way I found out that, when you insert words they should be sorted already.

**Tip 1:**
I inserted all my meanings into SQLite table, then SELECTed them in sorted way in order to insert into Realm. Now result is like this

```
r:351ms (18 times faster)
re:185ms
rea:95ms
rea:56ms
real:88ms
real:58ms
realm:83ms (39 times faster)
real:107ms
rea:110ms
rea:76ms
re:177ms
re:161ms
r:305ms
:5154ms (1.26 times faster)
```

**Tip 2:**
Turn off case sensitiveness in query. False is boolean to turn off case sensitive search. By doing this, I improved search by first character to 100ms.

```
query.beginsWith("key", word, false);
```

Answer (score 0):

Interesting use-case! I don't know your data set so I cannot suggest the optimal strategy but I can provide you with some ideas.

My suggestion is to separate the timings of `findAll()` and `sort()` to see which one is slowest under different conditions. After that I would experiment by sorting your data both alphabetically and by length, trying one at a time, or both in different order.

Also, about indexing, at the moment only `equalTo()` takes full advantage of the index, while `beginsWith()` is still lagging behind a bit (but we are working on making it as fast!).

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You should use `findAllSorted()` instead of `findAll()` and `sort()`.

Also, make sure you access the results directly (`results.get(i)`), instead of mapping it somewhere. I've seen people rip out their entire database into `ArrayList` and it's expected to be slow when people do that.